# Using Template Classes with CUDA keywords in generic classes

Tags: c++, cuda

I have created a template Class that wraps the Kernel functions. So that when ever another class needs use the kernel, it can simply call the class function without worrying about the CUDA terms and functionality. Since the class is template class all the definition and the declaration is included in the same file as below.

*Scanner.h*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ScanKernals.h"

class Scanner {
public :
    template<typename T>
    void ScanDevice(T * h_in, int size);

    template<typename T>
    void ScanHost();

};

template<typename T>
void Scanner::ScanHost()
{

}

template<typename T>
void Scanner::ScanDevice(T * h_in, int size)
{
  T * d_in;
  cudaMalloc(&d_in, size * sizeof(T));
  cudaMemcpy(d_in , h_in, size * sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  // runs kernel that is required to calculate the scan 
}
```

*ScanKernals.h*

```
template<typename T>
__global__
void scan(T * d_in, T* d_out, int size)
{
   // keranel code
}
```

The above class is then used in the main function as below

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Scanner.h"

int main()
{
    Scanner scanner;

    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile the code, the compiler gives errors, not recognizing CUDA specific keywords.

If I separate the definition of the *Scanner* class to a separate *.cpp* file this error will not be generated but since the **template classes cannot be declared and defined in two separate files**, this is not an option

Am I missing something here, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a code path which includes CUDA syntax containing code into a C++ compilation, there are two things you must do:

1. Compile the code using the nvcc compiler driver
2. Rename the file which is being compiled with a `.cu` extension. nvcc uses the file extension to determine the compilation trajectory of a given file, and if the file has a `.cpp` extension, the code will be passed directly to the host compiler and compilation will fail.

You are apparently failing to do one or perhaps both of these things.

Comment: could you elaborate on the *nvcc compiler driver*, are you mentioning nvrtc ?

Comment: I refer you to the front page of the nvcc documentation. Nvcc isn't a compiler, it is a compiler driver....

Comment: Then, I don't understand how your 1. helps. This is why I was asking. I naively assumed that @BAdhi was already using "nvcc compiler driver".

Comment: Please read the answer I wrote again. In it's entirety. I am simply saying there are two things you must do: use nvcc and use the right file extension. I don't know or much care which one he got wrong. That is what you must do to make this work. Incidentally, I strongly recommend *not* using the -x command line switch unless you really understand the full implications of it and carefully apply it file by file, because it can very undesirable side effects.

Comment: I think I got your answer. The -x flag contradicts your point 2. if I got it right. The fact that you *strongly recommend* not *using it* is fair, but does not remove this option. I believe developers are free to chose their file extension (maybe .cu is reserved in a larger piece of software for another concept). Finally, I believe you could express your opinion on the flag as a comment to the answer mentionning it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since we have a requirement that the main method should be implemented on a `.cpp` file. I couldn't do either of the suggestions you made. Instead I found a method to separate the template class between `.h` and `.cu` files which is described in [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48575/How-to-define-a-template-class-in-a-h-file-and-imp).

Answer (score 0):

Default behavior of nvcc on your files is not what you expected as @talonmies underlined. However, you may want to try the following compiler command-line option :

```
--x {c|c++|cu}                             (-x)
    Explicitly specify the language for the input files, rather than letting
    the compiler choose a default based on the file name suffix.
    Allowed values for this option:  'c','c++','cu'.
```

Specifying explicitly that your input code is cuda, even though named with a .cpp suffix. Here is an example `main.cpp` file:

```
__global__ void f() {}
```

Without the flag:

```
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin/nvcc -c main.cpp
main.cpp:1:1: error: ‘__global__’ does not name a type
 __global__ void f() {}
 ^
```

With the flag (no error):

```
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin/nvcc -c main.cpp -x cu
```

File naming freedom seems safe.